# What to do when context is null in fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception, android-context

Is it safe (correct) to simply return from method's and do nothing if context is null? currently I'm doing this when ever I need context from fragment.

```
Context context = getContext();
if(context == null) return;
```

My question is too stupid and obvious but I'm still not sure if this is correct. if its necessary or not. (maybe I should log warnings?)

---

I do this check in `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`, when getting context from `itemView` in view holders and inside view click listeners when ever needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think retrunning and doing nothing is as bad as catching an exception and swallowing it.

Fragment has a method `requireContext()`. It simply crashes the app when the context is null. Actually, I haven't never seen my app is crashed because of it. So I guess a null context in a fragment is a pretty rare and extreme case.

In the `onViewCreated`, you can also get context from the created view. It's non null because the view creation requires a context.

If you need some resources, you can also use `getResources().getString()` instead of `getContext().getString()`

Comment: Thanks, i think i can use `requireContext` for cases when im 100% sure its not null. like after `onAttach` is called as mentioned by @forpas

Answer (score 1):

Since your code is inside a fragment you must use:

```
getActivity()
```

to get the context of the host activity. 
Why do you get `null` context?
After `onAttach()` you can use `getContext()`

Comment: I never get null context, its just that i dont know if it will ever be null or not, because return type nullable. and how should i handle that.

Comment: If for every object we use in our code we write `if (obj != null)` then our classes would be filled with ifs and returns. If you know when every context is valid don't make so many checks.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i want to know! when context is valid?

Comment: See this link that mentions all about fragment lifecycle:https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-advanced-course-concepts/content/unit-1-expand-the-user-experience/lesson-1-fragments/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications/1-2-c-fragment-lifecycle-and-communications.html

Comment: Anyway the standard is that after `onAttach()`, `getContext()` is valid.